# Word 2013 custom keyboard shortcut for a new, custom tab?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In Microsoft Word 2013, how does one customize the keyboard shortcut for a new, custom tab (instead of using the keyboard shortcut which Word provides by default)?

Comment: I should really downvote this.. it's just that I can't yet. This is no forum for word 2013 shortcuts.. it's for helping each other on code's

Comment: The lack of a Word.SE site is irrelevant. There are *dozens* of MS Office help fora around the internet, and this question is off topic here.

Comment: @Jules, I think it's time to head to Area 51 to recommend Word.se and maybe hotkeys.se

Comment: Think broader. It would make sense to have an Office.SE; however, Hotkeys.SE is redundant, since there are immense lists of application hotkeys on the Internet already.

Comment: Office.SE would be just as redundant since superuser exists.  But that's as far as I'll go with that as it was meant to be a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File - Options - Customise Ribbon. There is a button at the bottom that says Keyboard Shortcuts and Customise beside it. Click it. Go to All Commands, Choose the one you want (New Tab in your case) and then customise your shortcut. Click Assign and then OK. Good to go!